# Errors with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I recently implemented `socket.io` and running into some strange errors.

The error messages I am getting aren't incredibly helpful and trying to figure out what is causing this.

Here are the contents of my `app.js` -

**app.js**

```
// Express Requirements
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
// Formidable Requirements
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8888);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// Non Default Code

// Socket.io Code
io.on('connection', function (client) {
  console.log("Client connected!");
  client.emit('newcommer',{status: true, newuser: 'paul'});
});
// End Socket.io Code

// End Non Default Code

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Error Message**

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/blah/blah/app.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
28 Nov 19:10:39 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Does anyone see anything that is off that could be causing this error?

Edits For Culprits:

Once these lines are removed then the code does not produce any errors:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Socket.io Code
io.on('connection', function (client) {
  console.log("Client connected!");
  client.emit('newcommer',{status: true, newuser: 'paul'});
});
// End Socket.io Code
```

Comment: `EADDRINUSE` means that some other server process is already listening on that port and thus you cannot start another one as only one server can listen to a given port at a time.

Comment: What do you see in the code which could be creating two processes? Once the code that I've listed in the question is removed, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are getting this error ???

I think you have another server running on the same port `server.listen(8888);`

Either close that running server or changer the port as `server.listen(8000);`

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing the output in the console right now. Changing the port doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Then try to run the code in steps. That amount of code is always hard to find the bug. Commented few code and test, find out on which stage it is working. Then add more code afterwards.

Comment: I know its related to the code that is required to implement socket.io. I will edit the question to include the culprits.